# IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name

Tags: java, веб-программирование, servlet, testng

Я новичек. Помогите исправить ошибку:

Дополняю.
Вот код html-страницы:

```
<form action="ContactServlet" method="post">
    Name: <input name="name" />
    Email: <input name="email"type="email" />
    Message: <input name="message" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

И код сервлета:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String message = request.getParameter("message");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    if(!message.equals(null)){
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        int port = 587;
        String username = "marina.lobko@gmail.com";
        String password = "***";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        String body = message;

        try {
            MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(session);
            m.setSubject(name);
            m.setFrom(new InternetAddress(email, null));
            m.setText(body);
            m.addRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(username, "me"));


            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, port, username, password);

            Transport.send(m);

        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (javax.mail.MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            writer.println("Message send!");
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Серверу пришел кривой запрос от клиента и он его не смог обработать. По идее можно просто скипать эти предупреждения)

Comment: а как найти этот кривой запрос?

Comment: Да например просто нажимаете несколько раз F5 в браузере и ошибка вполне может появиться

Comment: Просто я пытаюсь создать форму обратной связи на странице сайта. Когда запускаю код сайт открывается, но при переходе на страницу формы обратной связи 405 ошибка. И я в тупике...

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: добавила в текст вопроса

Comment: Marina Lobko и верните пожалуйста ошибку)

Comment: Я сейчас поднял сервлет на версии томката 7.0.108, ошибок не наблюдаю. Предлагаю диалог перенести в чат https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120362/https-ru-stackoverflow-com-questions-1250656-illegalargumentexception-invalid-c

Comment: ошибку вернула)) в чате не могу общаться: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq.

так что давайте тут)
у меня томкат 9.0.401 - поставить 7.0.108?

Comment: @Marina Lobko  гляньте url запроса, случаем не https://...? Если да, измените на http

Comment: ssl - что это? где это искать?
гляньте url запроса, случаем не https   -   вы об этом http://prntscr.com/10c53hh

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120368/discussion-between-marina-lobko-and-lampa).